# Vue JS - Retrieve date only

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, date

I'm making an api call which retrieves a set of objects. One of the objects returns a date and time together like this:

```
createdAt: "2020-11-04 09:48:32"
```

This is where I display the date and time:

```
<template v-for="item in collectedTrash">
        <BeforeAndAfter v-if="item.isPresented === 1"                            
                        :key="item.username"
                        :avatarUrl="require('@/assets/img/images/img_stats_km@2x.png')"
                        :imageBefore="getImageUrl(item.imageUrlBefore)"
                        :imageAfter="getImageUrl(item.imageUrlBefore)"
                        :username="item.username"
                        :date="item.createdAt"/> This is where I get the date
</template>
```

Is there anyway that I can retrieve the date only, rather than the date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you don't have access to the api and therefore have to process the date in your vue application.

Do you need the date as a date Object or is a string fine?
If a string representation is enough, you could use a library such as [Date fns](https://date-fns.org/) and use the format function:

```
...
:date="format(new Date(item.createdAt), 'yyyy-MM-dd')"
```

Another option might be to only use the first 10 characters of the string you received as the date: `date="item.createdAt.substring(0,9)"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like: `:date="item.createdAt.substr(0, 10)"`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the easiest way to format datetimes in JS it to use the Moment.js library (https://momentjs.com/). You could reformat the datetime string before passing it to your child component.

Or, if you don't want to rely on a third-party library and you know that the datetime string will always be passed in that format, I suppose you could do `item.createdAt.slice(0, 10)`.

Comment: I also just recently discovered that moment is considered a legacy project [Moment Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) and moment.js advise to not use moment.js in new projects.

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js can be very helpful with dates and times](https://momentjs.com/)

[Moment Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

moment("String").format('L'); // 04/11/2020